# Java PNG to JPG Bug

Tags: java, image-processing, png, jpeg

I am trying to convert a PNG image to a JPEG image following [this](http://www.codebeach.com/2007/06/convert-png-to-jpg-in-java.html) tutorial. But I encounter a problem. The resulting image has a pink layer.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Or what code should I use in order to convert the image into the desired format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not so much a tutorial as a couple of code snippets.  Can you upload the problem image?  How big is it in bytes?

Comment: Here it is a sample image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/samplepngimage.png/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a BufferedImage of desired size, e.g.:

   `BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)`
2. fill it with a proper background color:

   `img.getGraphics().fillRect(....)`
3. Call drawImage on the image's graphics atop of that background:

   `img.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`

then write down your image as JPG as usual.

Comment: See also graphics.drawImage with your chosen Color and a null ImageObserver : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-java.awt.Color-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-

Answer (score 4):

Which color mode are you using? While you create buffered image object, try adding the type like this option.

```
    File newFile = new File(path + fileName + "." + Strings.FILE_TYPE);

    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(url); // I was using an image from web
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    image = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    try {
        BufferedImage img = toBufferedImage(image);
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", newFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

private static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image src) {
    int w = src.getWidth(null);
    int h = src.getHeight(null);
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB; // other options
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
    Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: By now I have those 4 lines in the tutorial. And I don't know what are those variables: dest and src. How to declare them?